# Installing a package without including test code

Tags: python, pip

Running `pip install <package>` often results in test code being installed also.

For example, running

```
pip install pandas
```

gives me a folder with 422 files of test code.

What is the preferred way of installing a package without including the test code? Is there a way *other* than deleting these files myself after installing?

Comment: form the source code, changing the setup.py for not including the tests folder in the build file can help on this

Comment: @prashantrana That will only work with **your** packages. You cannot modify other packages.

Comment: @phd if we download the package whole source from the github, then it will work

Comment: Nobody installs packages this way. People use `pip install` to install from PyPI and VCS repositories. Even worse — people declare dependencies in `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` so that `pip` installs them automatically.

Comment: @phd it's better to use `pip` or `conda` to install package than using this way. I was just suggesting a method to solve OP problem. it's not a correct way to do so

Comment: So the answer to the OP question is — there is no way to do that in other people's packages.